# Biopython, PYTHONPATH, problems finding modules

Tags: module, pythonpath, biopython

I installed Biopython, but I am unable to get the computer to recognize the modules. For example, I create a text file in Komodo like this:

```
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import Seq
my_prot=Seq.Seq("AGTACACTGGT",IUPAC.protein)
```

and run it in terminal and receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bio.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
ImportError: No module named Bio.Alphabet
```

For the record, I can't get modules to import in interactive mode either. The documentation states that I can append the module search path by exporting to an environmental variable called PYTHONPATH (like with PATH), but when I type 'env' into the terminal, I see no environmental variable of the sort. I'm a biologist--not a computer scientist or programmer. Please bear with my naiveté if this sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find in which directory situated the module that you needs (Bio) and then add the path to the directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bio-python/
```

Instead of `/usr/local/bio-python/` you must specify the path that you've found.

To find the module you must use something like:

```
$ find / -name \*Bio\*
```

That is just an example. Of course it would be better if you could give some additional information (e.g. where you've installed the module and so on).

Comment: Ah, OK. Looks like I've gotten it to work by setting my PYTHONPATH the same way I would set a PATH. My question now is then: how do I make it so that I don't have to reassign the PYTHONPATH variable every time I start bash?

Comment: There are several options. The first one: you can add `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bio-python/` to `~/.bash_profile`. The second one: you can modify you script in such a way that it will add the directory to own PATH (`sys.path`) automatically. There are other ways also.

Comment: Thanks again, Igor. I modified my .bash_profile to include exporting my PYTHONPATH. The clouds have parted.

Comment: @user1480431: How did you install biopython? Generally, if you've installed a python module correctly, you don't need to monkey with PYTHONPATH to import it, since the install location should already be in the path.

Answer (score -2):

Press the start button, right click on my computer, select properties, go to advanced, click environment variables. Then find your path variable, and edit it by adding a semicolon, then your path. For example, if my path variable at the moment is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin", I can change it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;(PUT PATH HERE)"

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm running terminal in OS X, but I'll keep it in mind should I find myself needing to change PATH settings on a Windows PC.